# Can't log, and can't launch the console mode

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, virtual-console

After launch a game, I cannot log. The resolution of the logging page is low. I think that the nvidia drivers are corrupted.

So, I want to log with the (virtual) console mode and reinstall the drivers. But, I cannot!. After press <kbd>CTRL + ALT + F1</kbd> (..F4), the SSD disk lights are on, but the screen remains black.

I test with a usb key live, it's ok. But, I cannot, indeed, reinitialized the nvidia drivers like that.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You can boot in rescue mode and get text root shell. So, able to reinstall nvidia in that mode.

Comment: yes, i can.. but I've lost the root password. Fortunately,I've change it. Thanks